# AWK FS multiple separators include triming leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to use awk to split line by. and white-space including cut leading and trailing white-space. If I use -F"[ .]", the leading and trailing white-space cannot be ignored.

For example, this command will get `IPv4` because default FS will trim leading space:

```
echo "              IPv4 Input Packets............................1123330" | awk {print $1}`
```

But

```
echo "              IPv4 Input Packets............................1123330" | awk -F"[. ]" {print $1}
```

will get NONE.

How to get `IPv4` and `1123330` in `awk` using `print $1` and `print $4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a quantifier `+` in `FS` pattern.

```
s="              IPv4 Input Packets............................1123330"

awk -F '[. ]+' '{print $2, $5}' <<< "$s"

IPv4 1123330
```

Note that field numbers will start from `2` as first field will be empty.

You can also use `print $2, $NF` to get the same output.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But why is $1 empty? Is there a way that i can use $1 to get IPv4 and $4 to get 1123330 ?

Comment: I am not sure why but that is the behavior when we use any non-empty `FS` in awk. Even `awk -F '[[:blank:]]+'` leaves `$1` empty.

Comment: @vinllen : Not clear if you realize you can just use `$2` instead, right? Good luck.

Comment: `$1` is empty because, well, `$1` is empty. You told awk to split the record into fields separated by chains of spaces-or-periods. There is nothing before the first sequence of spaces-or-periods so the first field is null. The **ONLY** time awk treats leading/trailing spaces "specially" and ignores them during field splitting is when the FS is the default value of `" "` (a single blank char).

Comment: Yes that is what I meant that default `FS` of `" "` behaves **differently**. It splits fields not just on spaces but on tab characters as well. It effectively splits fields using `-F '[ \t]+'` and doesn't leave `$1` empty. However the moment we use `awk -F '[ \t]+'` in the code it will leave `$1` empty.

Answer (score 3):

You have to manually strip the leading/trailing spaces and then re-assign `$0` to force field splitting to happen again:

```
$ echo "              IPv4 Input Packets............................1123330" |
awk -F'[. ]+' '{sub(/^ +| +$/,""); $0=$0; print $1, $4}'
IPv4 1123330
```

If you want to include all FS characters in the stripping:

```
$ echo "              IPv4 Input Packets............................1123330" |
awk -F'[. ]+' '{sub("^"FS"|"FS"$",""); $0=$0; print $1, $4}'
IPv4 1123330
```